Is there a way to update a workflow file from a different workflow
I wanted to have a workflow run that would update the cronjob schedule of a different workflow based on when the first baseball game of the day is by changing a line of the file, however when I try it in a github workflow it says workflow 2 is not found and when I run ls -r inside workflow A there is no .github/workflows directory and by extension no workflow B, so I am unable to modify B from A.
I know the code that would be changing the line works because tested it locally it works so I assume issue is a github thing. Is there a way to edit 1 workflow file from the other in github actions?
Locally testing ls -R and other ls's were tried to see if could find workflow B from workflow A

I think if you put workflow 2 in a different repository, and then commit a change from repository 1 (workflow 1) into repository 2, that could work.
